# React elements vs DOM elements: what makes DOM elements so big?

Tags: reactjs

[Dan Abramov wrote a super article explaining the difference React components, elements, and instances.](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html) I am a bit confused about this statement therein:

> React elements are easy to traverse, don’t need to be parsed, and of
>   course they are much lighter than the actual DOM elements—they’re just
>   objects!

Aren't DOM elements also objects?

It would have made more sense to me if he wrote that React elements are much lighter than DOM elements because React elements have only two properties, "type" and "props", and actual DOM elements have hundreds of properties and methods. But the "they're just objects!" part is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I think he means is React elements like object `{1: '1'}`, but DOM elements it is HTMLElement.

So much element we can call Object because Array, NodeList, HTMLElement etc is Object if you use `instanceof`.